# Swift UnsafeMutablePointer: Must I call deinitialize before deallocate?

Tags: swift, memory-management, unsafemutablepointer

Given an instance of `UnsafeMutablePointer`, what's the point of calling `deinitialize(count:)` right before `deallocate(capacity:)`?

Can't you just call `deallocate(capacity:)`?

---

I saw this when reading the section "Using Typed Pointers" of the article [Unsafe Swift: Using Pointers And Interacting With C](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148569/unsafe-swift) on [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/).

The article contains the code below, which you can add to a new playground in Xcode.

> ```
> let count = 2
> let stride = MemoryLayout<Int>.stride
> let alignment = MemoryLayout<Int>.alignment
> let byteCount = stride * count
>
> do {
>   print("Typed pointers")
>
>   let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: count)
>   pointer.initialize(to: 0, count: count)
>   defer {
>     pointer.deinitialize(count: count)
>     pointer.deallocate(capacity: count)
>   }
>
>   pointer.pointee = 42
>   pointer.advanced(by: 1).pointee = 6
>   pointer.pointee
>   pointer.advanced(by: 1).pointee
>
>   let bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: count)
>   for (index, value) in bufferPointer.enumerated() {
>     print("value \(index): \(value)")
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The article explains below the code, if you keep reading.

> **Update**: as noted by user atrick in the comments below, deinitialization is only required for **non-trivial** types. That said, including deinitialization is a good way to future proof your code in case you change to something non-trivial. Also, it usually doesn’t cost anything since the compiler will optimize it out.