# Swift 4.1 deinitialize and deallocate(capacity:) deprecated

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers, swift4.1

I've been saying this to form a C array of CGPoint:

```
let arr = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>.allocate(capacity:4)
defer {
    arr.deinitialize()
    arr.deallocate(capacity:4)
}
arr[0] = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
arr[1] = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
arr[2] = CGPoint(x:50,y:50)
arr[3] = CGPoint(x:0,y:100)
```

Now (Swift 4.1 in the Xcode 9.3 beta) both `deinitialize` and `deallocate(capacity:)` are deprecated. It looks like what I'm supposed to say now might be:

```
defer {
    arr.deinitialize(count:4)
    arr.deallocate()
}
```

Is that right?

Comment: Note you don't have to call `.deinitialize` as `CGPoint` is a trivial type (if it wasn't a trivial type, i.e contained references, then you'd have to initialise the allocated memory before performing assignment, and then deinitialise afterwards).

Comment: @Hamish Yes, I'm always confused about this so I always say `deinitialize` just in case.

Comment: @Hamish see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814457/swift-unsafemutablepointer-must-i-call-deinitialize-before-deallocate - this is what I was "taught" too, just `deinitialize` because why not

Comment: Fair enough; though to be 100% foolproof, you would've wanted to have initialised the memory first by using one of the `.initialize` methods (before assignment through subscript, that is). You could also use a buffer pointer (https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/57320e2dbfbd0ad3ef68c69a97830eac).

Comment: @Hamish See, this is what I find so confusing. There you are doing the deinitialize on the `baseAddress`. But my code doesn't do that. So is my code wrong? I'm not getting any closer to clarity or certainty.

Comment: No your code isn't wrong. In the gist code I'm using a buffer pointer, which is just a pointer + count pair (the pointer component is called `baseAddress`). The deinitialisation of the `baseAddress` in my code is equivalent to the `arr.deinitialize(count:4)` that you do in your code. Buffer pointers don't currently expose a `deinitialize()` method, so that's why we have to extract the pointer and call it ourselves.

Comment: It seems  (from the defer statement) that the array is used only in some local scope. Is there a special reason not to use Swift array `let arr = [CGPoint(x:0,y:0), ...]` directly? You still can pass that to a C function, if necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is part of [SE-0184 Unsafe[Mutable][Raw][Buffer]Pointer: add missing methods, adjust existing labels for clarity, and remove deallocation size](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0184-unsafe-pointers-add-missing.md),
which has been implemented in Swift 4.1.

In particular:

> Removing capacity from deallocate(capacity:) will end the confusion over what deallocate() does, making it obvious that deallocate() will free the entire memory block at self, just as if free() were called on it.
>
> The old deallocate(capacity:) method should be marked as deprecated and eventually removed since it currently encourages dangerously incorrect code.