# deinitialize() was obsoleted in swift 5.0

Tags: swift

I was using a pod for ftp picture upload issue. But it is giving an error after I build the app with Swift 5.0.

**Here is the error:** 
*deinitialize()' is unavailable: the default argument to deinitialize(count:) has been removed, please specify the count explicitly.*

**Here is the Swift file belongs to pod:**

```
import Foundation

/* Resource type, values defined in `sys/dirent.h`. */
public enum ResourceType: String {
    case Unknown        = "Unknown"        // DT_UNKNOWN
    case Directory      = "Directory"      // DT_DIR
    case RegularFile    = "RegularFile"    // DT_REG
    case SymbolicLink   = "SymbolicLink"   // DT_LNK

case NamedPipe          = "NamedPipe"          // DT_FIFO
case CharacterDevice    = "CharacterDevice"    // DT_CHR
case BlockDevice        = "BlockDevice"        // DT_BLK
case LocalDomainSocket  = "LocalDomainSocket"  // DT_SOCK
case Whiteout           = "Whiteout"           // DT_WHT
}

open class ResourceItem: CustomStringConvertible {
    open var type: ResourceType = .Unknown
    open var name: String = ""
    open var link: String = ""
    open var date: Date = Date()
    open var size: Int = 0
    open var mode: Int = 0
    open var owner: String = ""
    open var group: String = ""
    open var path: String = "/"

open var description: String {
    get {
        return "\nResourceItem: \(name), \(type.rawValue)"
    }
}
}


private let _resourceTypeMap: [Int:ResourceType] = [
    Int(DT_UNKNOWN): ResourceType.Unknown,
    Int(DT_FIFO):    ResourceType.NamedPipe,
    Int(DT_SOCK):    ResourceType.LocalDomainSocket,
    Int(DT_CHR): ResourceType.CharacterDevice,
    Int(DT_DIR): ResourceType.Directory,
    Int(DT_BLK): ResourceType.BlockDevice,
    Int(DT_REG): ResourceType.RegularFile,
    Int(DT_LNK): ResourceType.SymbolicLink,
    Int(DT_WHT): ResourceType.Whiteout
]

/** Operation for resource listing. */
internal class ResourceListOperation: ReadStreamOperation {

fileprivate var inputData: NSMutableData?
var resources: [ResourceItem]?

override func streamEventEnd(_ aStream: Stream) -> (Bool, NSError?) {
    var offset = 0
    let bytes = self.inputData!.bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: (self.inputData?.length)!)
    let totalBytes = CFIndex(self.inputData!.length)
    var parsedBytes = CFIndex(0)
    let entity = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFDictionary>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    var resources = [ResourceItem]()
    repeat {
        parsedBytes = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(nil, bytes.advanced(by: offset), totalBytes - offset, entity)
        if parsedBytes > 0 {
            let value = entity.pointee?.takeUnretainedValue()
            if let fptResource = value {
                resources.append(self.mapFTPResources(fptResource))
            }
            offset += parsedBytes
        }
    } while parsedBytes > 0
    self.resources = resources
    entity.deinitialize()
    return (true, nil)
}

fileprivate func mapFTPResources(_ ftpResources: NSDictionary) -> ResourceItem {
    let item = ResourceItem()
    if let mode = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceMode as String] as? Int {
        item.mode = mode
    }
    if let name = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceName as String] as? String {
        // CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing assumes that teh names are in MacRoman.
        // To fix it we create data from string and read it with correct encoding.
        // https://devforums.apple.com/message/155626#155626
        if configuration.encoding == String.Encoding.macOSRoman {
            item.name = name
        } else if let nameData = name.data(using: String.Encoding.macOSRoman) {
            if let encodedName = NSString(data: nameData, encoding: self.configuration.encoding.rawValue) {
                item.name = encodedName as String
            }
        }
        item.path = self.path! + item.name
    }
    if let owner = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceOwner as String] as? String {
        item.owner = owner
    }
    if let group = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceGroup as String] as? String {
        item.group = group
    }
    if let link = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceLink as String] as? String {
        item.link = link
    }
    if let size = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceSize as String] as? Int {
        item.size = size
    }
    if let type = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceType as String] as? Int {
        if let resourceType = _resourceTypeMap[type] {
            item.type = resourceType
        }
    }
    if let date = ftpResources[kCFFTPResourceModDate as String] as? Date {
        item.date = date
    }
    return item
}

override func streamEventHasBytes(_ aStream: Stream) -> (Bool, NSError?) {
    if let inputStream = aStream as? InputStream {
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 1024)
        let result = inputStream.read(buffer, maxLength: 1024)
        if result > 0 {
            if self.inputData == nil {
                self.inputData = NSMutableData(bytes: buffer, length: result)
            } else {
                self.inputData!.append(buffer, length: result)
            }
        }
        buffer.deinitialize()
    }
    return (true, nil)
}

}
```

Can you help me how can I fix these 2 below lines:

```
buffer.deinitialize()
entity.deinitialize()
```

And is it okay if we fix these two lines? I mean does the pod work after we fix these two lines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48570455/1780632 hope it resolve your issue

Comment: @jawadAli thanks I have read it. But how can I fix these two lines? Can you able to help me to writing solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deinitialize` now requires a `count` parameter indicating how many values you want to deinitialise.

From the context, the code is probably trying to deinitialise everything the pointer references, so the number of values we deinitialise will be equal to the number of values we `allocate`. This will be `1024` for `buffer` and `1` for `entity`.

You should replace those lines with:

```
buffer.deinitialize(count: 1024)
// and
entity.deinitialize(count: 1)
```

respectively

However, since this is code from a pod that you are modifying, make sure to check the terms in the licence of the pod to make sure you are not violating anything.

You should also inform the author of the pod that the pod needs updating. This API change is made in Swift 4.1, I think, so it's quite old.