# Should I call free if I am getting an UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift?

Tags: swift, memory-management

I am using a variable inside a function with holds and `UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t>`. Should I call `free` on it?

```
func logProps() {
    var count: UInt32 = 0
    let _propArr = class_copyPropertyList(cls, &count)
    // ...
    // free(propArr)  // ?
}
```

---

On a different note, is `free` same as using `deallocate` ([Swift UnsafeMutablePointer: Must I call deinitialize before deallocate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46814457/10900045)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because of the name of the method. `class_copyPropertyList` includes the word "copy" which indicates that the buffer belongs to you. Note that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418553-class_copypropertylist#) also indicates this:

> You must free the array with free().

So you should use `free()` to destroy this buffer. This is currently identical to calling `.deallocate()`, [but that is not promised](https://forums.swift.org/t/unsafemutablepointer-allocation-compatibility-with-c-malloc-free/21713/2?u=cocoaphony), so follow the instructions as given.

(Thanks to MartinR for running down the question of free vs deallocate.)

Comment: *"... the C function free is called deallocate in Swift"* – not really. The C function `free()` still exists under that name. `deallocate()` is a method of UnsafeMutablePointer (the counterpart of `allocate()`) which calls `Builtin.deallocRaw`, which *might* be the same as  or compatible to `free()`, but that is not documented.

Comment: @MartinR I struggled a lot writing that, and still don't have the right answer in my head. Do we know that calling `free` is promised to be correct in a way that we don't know calling `.deallocate` is? The documentation for class_copyPropertyList says to use `free()`, but it also says that it returns NULL, which doesn't exist in Swift. My point being these docs aren't explaining Swift; we're expected to make Swift translations. So should we take "call free" to mean literally "call free" or "deallocate the UnsafeMuatablePointer?" If free/deallocate diverge, which would be correct Swift?

Comment: My gut feeling is that there should be no case where `.deallocate` is wrong to deallocate the pointer's uninitialized/trivial memory. The docs for `.deallocate` do not say "that was allocated with `.allocate`. They say "Deallocates the memory block previously allocated at this pointer." (But I'm not completely certain about this; I'm just trying to nail down what practice we should be adopting and how we should know.)

Comment: If class_copyPropertyList says to use free() then we can assume that the memory is allocated with malloc(). The return value is an optional, and C NULL pointers are mapped to nil in Swift. I would follow the docs and use free, but I do not know if it makes a difference. – I am still struggling  to find out what Builtin.deallocRaw actually *does.*

Comment: Let's ask the experts: https://forums.swift.org/t/unsafemutablepointer-allocation-compatibility-with-c-malloc-free/21713

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for running this down. I've fixed the answer.